# Regression with one group having just zeros as input

Tags: regression, zero-inflation, linear-probability-model

I want to analyse the effect of the sports membership fee on the cancellation probability with a simple regression. When a person leaves a sports club (Cancel = 1), their membership fee is automatically set to 0, as they no longer have to pay. This leads to a particular situation in my dataset:

Individuals who leave/are no member (Cancel = 1) automatically have MembershipFee = 0.
Individuals who remain members (Cancel = 0) have varying values for Membership fees.

Since MembershipFee = 0 applies to all individuals who leave, this can lead to a distortion in the data, since all datapoins at Cancel = 1 are at 0.
With the panel data, I attempted to investigate the relationship between membership fee in the previous year (t-1) and membership status (Cancel) in the current year (t) but there where no big changes to see. In addition, I have about 3x more data for the people who are still members.

What is the best way to conduct a reasonable analysis? The goal is to create a simple linear probability model.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to need here is to look a the membership fees *prior* to the decision to leave or stay. No problem getting this for the leavers, but you need it for a group of people who stay.

One way to do this is to try to match the leavers with members who decided to stay. There are lots of ways to match people and you can find info on that in books or by browsing the [matching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matching) tag here. One common method is propensity score. You would need to consider what variables you want to use for the match -- demographics, distance to club, age, sex, etc.

There are probably methods other than matching as well.

Comment: thank you very much peter!